# Including shared library in C++ Eclipse project

Tags: c++, eclipse, shared-libraries

I created a shared library in c++. I copied my .so file into /usr/local/include/ folder and I referenced my library in the linker (I included the -ldl too), but when I write the #include in my new project I have an "Unresolved Inclusion" warning.

What can I do to solve this?

Step 1: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/24/step1f.png/

Step 2: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/827/step2i.png/

Thanks for advance.

Comment: And this is the 3th step
Step 3: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/820/step3nw.png/

Comment: Dynamic libraries should be in the `lib` directory, and header files in the `include` directory.

Comment: Thanks @JoachimPileborg ! Works perfectly! But I don't understand why I don't need to copy the header file for pthread library :(

Comment: marc: header for pthread library is probably installed to some directory that's searched by default

Comment: Thanks @dbrank0 I saw it after my question, sorry. I'm C# developer, things are pretty different in Eclipse/C++ :D